# How to strip rest of the information from a cell and keep only a portion?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

if possible I would like to strip everything and get the Order ID.
the problem is: Location of the order ID and sometimes it begins with `A` or `1`.

- Cell Example A1: `{"Ref":"bad order","OrderId":"ABSER27"}`
- Cell Example A2: `{"OrderId":"ABSER27"}`
- Cell Example A3: `{"order_id":"12345678","customer_email":"BADORDER@gmail.com"}`
- Desired result: B1 =  `ABSER27`
- Desired result: B3 =  `ABSER27`
- Desired result: B3 =  `12345678`

Comment: I think you'll need vba.  Loop through the cells to find for a regexp version of orderid that covers all possibilities, then either look for the opening quotes, or offset by three (quotes, colon, quotes) and copy til next (closing) quotes.

Comment: What do you mean, “sometime it begins with `A` or `1`”?  If beginning with `A` or `1` isn't the defining characteristic, how do we tell where the Order ID begins?

Answer (score 1):

Life can be easier with Excel's "Text to column" function.

**Step 1 - Chop the strings into columns**

First, strip the leading `{` and trailing `}`.  You can do it with replace function, or if you want to do it with a function, `=MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-2)`.

That will result in source data like:
[image]

Next, select column A (without `{ }`) and from the ribbon, select Data > Data Tools > Text to Columns.  Use the following options:
[image]
[image]

Then you will have the information presented neatly in 4 columns:
[image]

**Step 2 - Pick order id from the columns**

After that, you can do whatever you want to do to pick up the order id.  A simple one would be putting a formula in, say, column G with cell G1 having the below formula:

```
=INDIRECT("RC"&MATCH("order*id",A1:F1,0)+1,FALSE)
```

Since "OrderId" may as well be in the form "order_id" from the example, we use a wildcard `*` to do the matching. The formula will then fetch the cell to the right of "OrderId".
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In cell B2 use the Mid function

Text =A2

Start Number = Use Search function (search is not case sensitive whereas Find is) to locate position of "id" in cell A2 starting from position 1 then add the number of characters to the Order Number.

Number of characters is the difference of the start number to the next double quote (ASCII Character 34) position.

```
=MID(A2,SEARCH("id",A2,1)+5,(FIND(CHAR(34),A2,(SEARCH("id",A2,1)+5))-(SEARCH("id",A2,1)+5)))
```

**EDIT to allow for additional "ID/id" in Email field or order id without need for addin or VBA**

Wrap true and false MID statements inside an IF that checks there there is more than one id and that the email address is not the first comma separated field.

```
 =IF(
AND((LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A2),("ID"),"")))/LEN("ID")>1,ISERROR(FIND("@",LEFT(A2,FIND(",",A2)-1),1))=FALSE),

MID(A2,
FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A2),"ID","~",2),1)+5,
FIND(CHAR(34),A2,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A2),"ID","~",2),1)+5)-(FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A2),"ID","~",2),1)+5)
),

MID(A2,
SEARCH("ID",A2,1)+5,
(FIND(CHAR(34),A2,(SEARCH("ID",A2,1)+5))-(SEARCH("ID",A2,1)+5))
)
)
```

Comment: Same issue, as with Scott's answer, it may give wrong results if other fields also contain "id".

Comment: @Máté Juhász   updated to accommodate your comment

Answer (score 0):

For this type of problems I use [Regex Find/Replace add-in](http://www.codedawn.com/regex-find-replace-download.php)
(*I'm not affiliated in any way with it, just an enthusiast user*)

With that you can use regular expressions, e.g.:
`=RegExReplace(UPPER(A1),".*ORDER_?ID"":""([^""]+)"".*","$1")`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Based on the information you’ve presented —
Order ID runs from the first `A` or `1` in the field,
up to the first following `"` (quote) — this is not difficult. 
It’s easiest if we use a few “helper columns”:

- `C1` → `=IFERROR(FIND("A",$A1), LEN($A1)+1)`
- `D1` → `=IFERROR(FIND("1",$A1), LEN($A1)+1)`
- `E1` → `=MIN($C1,$D1)`
- `F1` → `=FIND("""", $A1, $E1)`

`C1` and `D1` find the first `A` and `1`, respectively, in cell `A1`. 
If there isn’t any, `FIND` returns an error,
and, using `IFERROR`, we set the value to the length of `A1` plus one;
i.e., the offset of the next character after the last character. 
`E1` is the smaller of these;
so, if at least one `A` or `1` was found, `E1` points to the first one. 
If there aren’t any, then it is also length+1.

And now `F1` finds the first `"` after the above. 
If there isn’t a `"`, this is an error. 
If there wasn’t an `A` or a `1`, `E1` is the length of `A1`+1,
and so `F1` is also an error.

So finally we set

- `B1` → `=IF(ISERROR($F1), "ERROR", MID($A1, $E1, $F1-$E1))`

If `F1` is an error, just display an `ERROR` indicator. 
Otherwise, extract the substring from the MIDdle of `A1`,
starting at the location of the `A` or `1`,
and with a length that takes it up to (but not including) the delimiting `"`.

Comment: Possible problem if that *"customer_email":"BADORDER@gmail.com"* comes before the order_id in sequence, or *"ref":"bad order"* gets capitalised

Comment: I stated my understanding of the requirements, and asked the OP for clarification. Based on my understanding of the requirements, the input you suggest cannot/will not occur.

Comment: hence, 'possible'.  I notice sometimes the order_id is the first item, sometimes it's not.  I presume, since 'order_id' can be title case or sometimes have underscore, that other things can change, too.